# how to identify "reply" annotation in itext

Tags: annotations, itext

I am using itext to extract annotations in pdf, however I am not able to differentiate replied annotations.... Currently I am using PdfName.IRT which returns a string.. but I don't know how to get the annotation to which it is replied to...please find the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\PDF\\test.pdf");
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        PdfArray array = reader.getPageN(i).getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
        if (array == null) continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {

            PdfDictionary annot = array.getAsDict(j);
            if(annot.getAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS)!=null)
            {

            System.out.println(annot.getAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS));
            System.out.println(annot.getAsString(PdfName.T));
            System.out.println(annot.get(PdfName.CREATIONDATE));
            System.out.println(annot.get(PdfName.IRT));
            System.out.println("--------");
            }
        }
    }

}
```